# Using parameters in regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to use NotePad++ to do a search and replace using the regex function that replaces a string of characters but maintains one part of the string. My description isn't very good so perhaps it will be better if I just give you the example.

Throughout and xml doc I have the following elements...

```
<AddressLine3>addressLine3>
<AddressLine2>addressLine2>
```

I want to replace these with

```
<addressLine3> <addressLine2>
```

So I need to maintain the address line number.

I know that

```
AddressLine([0-9]{1})>addressLine([0-9]{1})
```

is a valid reg ex but I'm not sure what to put in the replace with section to tell it to maintain whatever value was found by ([0-9]{1}).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's `\{number of the group}`, so `\1`, `\2`, ...

Edit with your precisions (I changed a bit your regex for simpler groups):

`(AddressLine[0-9]{1}>)(addressLine[0-9]{1})` is replaced by `\2`

Comment: In the replace section, you'd use `$1` instead of `\1`. And the replace string is `$1`, not `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture it in group and replace them

Find:`(AddressLine[0-9])>(addressLine[0-9])`

Replace:`$1 <$2`

Comment: In the replace section, you'd use `$1` instead of `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Find what : `(<AddressLine\d>)AddressLine\d`
Replace by: `$1`

You have to select the choice `regular expression`